# C# DateTime Format issue in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am formating my datetime column based on the culture (en-GB), which is fetched from my database. And I am exporting this data to excel. When I download my data some datetime's are displayed like this "16/10/2013 16:34:14" (i.e, 24 Hours) which is correct and others are displayed like this "11/10/2013  12:47:01 PM" (i.e, 12 Hours) which is wrong. For en-GB the datetime format should be "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss". 
How to solve this issue. Kindly advice me. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code which i used to export the data to Excel.

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = dtTemp; // Here is My data 
gv.DataBind();

Response.Clear();

// 'set the response mime type for excel
string fileName = string.Empty;
fileName = "Online_Topup_Report_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(DayFormat.Value.ToString().Replace("/", "-")).ToString() + ".xls";
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + "");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
// 'create an htmltextwriter which uses the stringwriter
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

// 'tell the datagrid to render itself to our htmltextwriter
gv.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Output.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Is Excel running in the en-GB culture?  If not, that might explain the discrepancy.  In general, it's best to avoid culture-specific formatting in an interchange format, which is basically what you're doing.  Could you use one of the "universal" DateTime formats like "u", "U", or "R" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Note that even if the raw date is in a less-readable format, Excel can display it in your preferred format.

Comment: No my system is running in US format. whether it is running on UK or US is not a problem. I just formatting it based on the culture. After fetched from DB, I have formatted that column in to datetime as 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' and then converted it to string. After doing all these only i would export it to Excel.

Comment: Right... and Excel sees the formatted date and tries to display it in it's standard en-US date format, which is probably a 12-hour format.  In those cases where you're still seeing the en-GB format, Excel is probably _not_ recognizing the value as a date, and displaying it as text (which means you still see the en-GB formatting).  This is why I said you should avoid culture-specific formatting when you're exporting/importing DateTime values.  (Ideally, you also avoid time zones, for similar reasons, and only use GMT times.)

Comment: @Santhosh29 did you found a solution for this? this is my problem currently.

Answer (score 0):

You should format first datetime whatever you are getting from Database to format:
       "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

and then you can export  it to excel.

Comment: I think in your case somewhere while formatting something is going wrong .therefore its not formatting all datetime.

Comment: Yes, After fetched from DB, I have formatted that column in to datetime as 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' and then converted it to string. After doing all these only i would export it to Excel. But nothing worked. It displays as i mentioned in my first post. Please advice me....?